# Elasticsearch: sum of total term frequency in ONE document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I need sumttf of ONE document in a field. However I can get sumttf of all documents only... 
I need to be able to access the variable in script like _index['field'].sumttf() of that particular document. This is what I've got so far.

Mapping:

```
{"document2" : {
  "mappings" : {
    "document2" : {
      "_all" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "content" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "term_vector" : "yes",
          "fields" : {
            "with_shingles" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_shingle_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        ...
```

Term vector:

```
"_index" : "document2",
"_type" : "document2",
"_id" : "709718",
"_version" : 1,
"term_vectors" : {
    "content" : {
      "field_statistics" : {
        "sum_doc_freq" : 60676474,
        "doc_count" : 198373,
        "sum_ttf" : 224960172
      },
      terms" : {
        "0" : {
          "term_freq" : 8
        },
        "0.5" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        "003a0e45ea07a" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        "005" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        "0081989" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        "01" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        "01.08.2002" : {
          "term_freq" : 1
        },
        ...
```